# Unable to automatically create session and invoke validation methods when using custom authentication in Parse Server

Tags: parse-platform

Unable to automatically create session and invoke validation methods when using custom authentication in Parse Server

I'm using Parse Server as the backend and trying to implement user authentication using a custom authentication method. I have implemented the custom authentication module CustomAuth.js and registered it in index.js.

Problem 1:
I'm facing an issue where the session is not automatically created, resulting in the inability to obtain a session token. When calling the user authentication method Parse.User.logInWith('myAuth', authData) or user.linkWith('myAuth',authData), no new session data is generated.

Problem 2:
Additionally, I have added console.log() statements in the validateAuthData() and validateAppId() methods of the custom authentication module for debugging purposes. However, I noticed that these methods are not being invoked.

Here is my code example:

CustomAuth.js:

```
const CustomAuth = {
  validateAuthData(authData) {
    // 在此处添加验证 authData 的逻辑
    console.log('validateAuthData() 被调用');
    return Promise.resolve({})
  },
  
  validateAppId(appId, authData) {
    // 在此处添加验证 appId 和 authData 的逻辑
    console.log('validateAppId() 被调用');
    return Promise.resolve({})
  }
};

module.exports = CustomAuth;
```

index.js:

```
const ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
const express = require('express');
const CustomAuth = require('./CustomAuth.js');
async function build(){
    const app = express();
    const api = new ParseServer({
        databaseURI: 'mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/HRM',
        cloud: './cloud/main.js',
        appId: '1000073',
        appName: "byHRM",
        masterKey: 'xxxx',
        port: 10086,
        mountPath: "/api",
        javascriptKey: "xxxxx",
        // logLevel: "verbose",
        auth: {
            myAuth: {
                module: CustomAuth,
                option1: 'hello',
                option2: 'world',
            }
        },
    });
    await api.start()
    app.use('/api', api.app);

    const port = 10086;
    app.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
    });
}

build()
```

cloud/main.js:

```
 const provider = {
      authenticate: async (options) => {
        console.log('111',this,'222',options,'成功',options.success.toString(),'失败',options.error.toString())
          options.success(provider, {
            id:11234,
            sessionToken:"kdsafjoweinldjaslfdaskjl"
          });
      },
      restoreAuthentication() {
        console.log('222')
        return true;
      },
    
      getAuthType() {
        console.log('333')
        return 'myAuth';
      },
    
      async getAuthData(code) {
        console.log('444')
        const api = new QwAPI('/auth/getuserinfo','GET')
        const data =  await api.request({code})
        return data
      },
    };

// 注册自定义认证模块
Parse.User._registerAuthenticationProvider(provider );

// 用户认证方法
Parse.Cloud.define('authenticateUser', async (request) => {
  const query = request.params
    let authData
    if(!query.code){
      error = '请传入有效code值'
      console.error(error)
      return error
    }else {
      authData = {code: query.code}
    }
    const user = new Parse.User()
    const res = await user.linkWith('myAuth',authData,{ useMasterKey: true }); //use Parse.User.logInWith is the same

  try {

    const sessionToken = user.getSessionToken();
    console.log('会话令牌:', sessionToken);

    return {
      sessionToken: sessionToken
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('认证失败:', error);
    throw new Parse.Error(Parse.Error.OBJECT_NOT_FOUND, '认证失败');
  }
});
```

#### Environment

Server

- Parse Server version: `6.1.0-alpha.12`
- Operating system: `Windows 11`
- Local or remote host (AWS, Azure, Google Cloud, Heroku, Digital Ocean, etc): `Local`

Database

- System (MongoDB or Postgres): `MongoDB`
- Database version: `5.0.5`
- Local or remote host (MongoDB Atlas, mLab, AWS, Azure, Google Cloud, etc): `Local`

Client

- SDK (iOS, Android, JavaScript, PHP, Unity, etc): `JavaScript`
- SDK version: `4.0.1`

Could you please help me resolve these issues? Why is the session not being created automatically, and why are the validation methods not being invoked? Thank you!

Attached are the code snippets and relevant information. I appreciate your patience and guidance!

Comment: Would it work if you try to first `signUp()` user with username and password and then `linkWith()` your custom auth service?